# Что необходимо для того, чтобы программа воспроизвела нажатие мышки или клавиатуры?

Tags: python-3.x

Хотелось бы сделать простенького бота.Для этого необходимо, чтобы программа могла нажать куда-либо, еще лучше если бы смогла что-либо написать потом.
  Например прочла бы сообщение и выдала нужный ответ, предварительно кликнув куда надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) или модуль win32api.